# File Filtering with awk with brackets

Tags: linux, awk

I am just using `awk` to filter some contents from the file in Linux which is simple and i am able to get what is needed but i little fail to understand the logic. I hope someone will make it clear for me and other like me.

1- File contents are like below ...

```
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] -> [cnf76628] succeeded
```

2- What I'm trying to do is to get user ID's which are within `[]` as follows.

```
# awk -F'[][]' '/authentication for user/{print $2}' test_file
```

So, what I'm failed to understand is why `$2` is the User ID as its fifth column where it exits but it takes `$2` though? Does it mean the string I'm looking like `authentication for user` is getting considered $1 as a starting point?.

Any clarity will be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that `[][]` splits the records/lines with single brackets, `]` or `[`, into fields so the ID is not in the 5th field, but the second one. If you remove `-F'[][]'` the default separator would be used, whitespaces, and the ID would land in Field 5 then.

Comment: Please run following test: what you get if you replace `$2` using `$1`? what you get if you replace `$2` using `$3`?

Comment: This is a classic case of the difference between the 5th column in your mind vs the 5th column in your code. In such situations your mind loses :-). Change your script to `awk -F'[][]' '/authentication for user/{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++) print i, "<" $i ">"; exit}' test_file` so you can see what the columns are in your code. The `/authentication for user/` test is doing nothing useful given your posted sample input btw, you could just remove it.

Comment: for future reference, consider providing a set of sample input data whereby some of the rows match your processing requirements and some do not; your current sample consists of the same exact row repeated 29 times so your test - `/authentication for user/` - would appear to be unnecessary since it occurs on every line; I'm guessing your *real* data has some lines that don't include `/authentication for user/`. as well as different user IDs (other than `cnf76628`), in which case you'll likely get a better response if you provide a sample of the *real* data

Answer (score 1):

`-F` defines the field separators - by default spaces or tabs.

`-F'[abc]'` defines `a` **or** `b` **or** `c` as separators, and thus `-F'[[]]'` makes either `[` or `]` separate a field.

With that in mind, the second field comes between the first and second separators.

Answer (score 1):

Your field separator regex matches either `[` or `]`, and each of the line ("records") above are actually split into seven fields (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4iZOzv/1)):

[image]

When you use `/authentication for user/` it checks for the presence of `authentication for user` anywhere on a line, i.e. in the `$0` field. However, `authentication for user` is present in Field 1, so your understanding is right.

So, the consfusion comes from the fact that `[][]` splits the records/lines with single brackets, `]` or `[`, into fields so the ID is not in the 5th field, but the second one. If you remove `-F'[][]'` the default separator would be used, whitespaces, and the ID would land in Field 5 then.

Answer (score 1):

The approach fails for obvious reasons since you're defining the separator, not the field.

Here's one way to get what you had in mind. It places the fields with a starting `[` and a trailing `]` at the end of the line which can be accessed with `$(K+1)`, `$(K+2)` etc.

```
$ awk '/authentication for user/{ K=NF; x=NF; 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
      if($i~/^\[/&&$i~/\]$/){ 
        x++; gsub("\[|\]","",$i); $x=$i } } 
    print $(K+1),$(K+3) } END{ print "A full line:\n"$0 }' file
cnf76628_1 cnf76628_3
cnf76628_1 cnf76628_3
cnf76628_1 cnf76628_3
A full line:
check_ntlm_password: authentication for user cnf76628_1 -> cnf76628_2 -> cnf76628_3 succeeded cnf76628_1 cnf76628_2 cnf76628_3
```

##### Data

```
cat file
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628_1] -> [cnf76628_2] -> [cnf76628_3] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628_1] -> [cnf76628_2] -> [cnf76628_3] succeeded
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [cnf76628_1] -> [cnf76628_2] -> [cnf76628_3] succeeded
```

Answer (score 1):

With `-F[...]` the outer brackets denote that the contents (`...`) are to be considered one by one in an **OR** fashion, eg, `-F'[ab]'` says to look for the character `a` **OR** `b`

While `-F[[]]` would seem to indicate that we want to look for the characters `[` **OR** `]`, these 2 characters (in this order) are treated specially, eg, as delimiters of a [character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html); example: `-F'[[:space:]]'`

In order to search for the literal characters `[` **OR** `]` we need to switch their order when specifying them: `-F'[][]'`